# How to update preconditioner in scipy.optimize.newton_krylov

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am trying to solve a sample nonlinear problem and I want to setup a preconditioner for newton_krylov solver of scipy.optimize.

I set the preconditioner by the LinearOperator using spilu. The Matrix is changing with the independent variable, i.e., matrix M(x), and M(x) needs to be updated as like F(x), the residual, in each nonlinear iteration.

It seems the "inner_M" option in newton_krylov is only called once the LinearOperator at the beginning of the process. How I can set the "inner_M" preconditioner option to perform M(x) update in each newton iteration?

Specifically, I can not understand the description in 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton_krylov.html
for the "inner_M" setup:

"...If the preconditioner has a method named ‘update’, it will be called as update(x, f) after each nonlinear step, with x giving the current point, and f the current function value."

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Following the example under
    [doc/scipy/ ... still-too-slow-precondition](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#still-too-slow-precondition),
set `M.update` to a function which copies `x` to a global, here `xglo`.
Or, make a class with `self.xupdate`.

```
    xglo = None

    def get_preconditioner():
        ...
        J1_ilu = spilu(J1)  # better spsolve ?

        M = LinearOperator(shape=(nx*ny, nx*ny), matvec=J1_ilu.solve)

        #.......................................................................
        def xglobal( x, F ):
            """ newton_krylov calls this at each iteration: xglo = x """
            global xglo
            xglo = x.copy()
            print( "update: x %s  F %s " % (nu.asum(x), nu.asum(F)) )  # test
                # nu.asum: array summary, size min av max

        M.update = xglobal

        return M
```

(I don't know if this is really a good idea -- depends on your preconditioner.
scicomp.stack might be a better place to ask, see e.g.
    [when-is-newton-krylov-not-an-appropriate-solver](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10177/when-is-newton-krylov-not-an-appropriate-solver)
 .)